# Unable to get thymeleaf form data in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am new to Thymeleaf, I try to execute a simple form submittion example using Thymeleaf and Spring MVC. I wrote the code according to Thymeleaf documentation. But I am getting null values in the controller.

```
<form action="thymeleafexample/thymeleaf.html" th:action="@{/thymeleaf}"
      th:object="${loginModel}" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td th:text="#{emp.empId.label}">Emp ID</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{empId}"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td th:text="#{emp.empName.label}">Emp Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{empName}"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="submit" name="save" th:text="#{${'.emp.button.label'}}">submit</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and my Controller is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/thymeleaf", params = {"save"})
public String save(@Validated LoginModel loginModel, final BindingResult bindingResult, ModelMap model) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "thymeleaf";
    }
    System.out.println(loginModel);
    System.out.println(loginModel.getEmpName());
    return "/thymeleaf";
}
```

and my Model class is

```
public class LoginModel {

    private String empName;
    private int empId;

    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }
}
```

Comment: <form action="thymeleafexample/thymeleaf.html" th:action="@{/thymeleaf}" th:object="${loginModel}" method="post">
<table>
   <tr>
      <td th:text="#{emp.empId.label}">Emp ID</td>
    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{empId}"/></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td th:text="#{emp.empName.label}">Emp Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{empName}"/></td>
    </tr><tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <button type="submit" name="save" th:text="#{${'.emp.button.label'}}">submit</button>

Comment: Is your controller method actually getting invoked correctly?

Comment: thaks for your reply, yeah its invoking correctly.

Comment: Try removing `params={"save"}` and let me know

Comment: i tried but same result is coming

Comment: Have you override the constructor for the model class ? The default one without parameter is required

Comment: Did you get this solved? Are you using `@SessionAttribute("loginModel")` in your controller? Or, did you try using `@Valid @ModelAttribute` in your controller?

Comment: thank you forn your answers frnds, i missed the constructor in model class, i set it, i got the result

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and [as OP mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671221/unable-to-get-thymeleaf-form-data-in-spring-mvc/33758149#comment38402215_24671221), creating a constructor for the POJO(Model) class with necessary member fields and using `th:field=*{foo}` instead of `th:value=${foo}` solved my issue.